# How to make a page to not appear in the menu when created?

Tags: menus, pages

When one creates a page in the Dashboard (Pages -> Create new) it always appears in the menu and that is the way it should be.

But now I want to create a page that does *not* appear in the menu at all. How do I do that?

I'm using a plugin called [Nice navigation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/nice-navigation/) for animated menus and the theme I'm using is called [Fiver](http://wordpress.org/themes/fiver)

[Here](http://brfrodakvarn.se) is the site I'm working on.

Edit:

This Nice navigation plugin has an arguments box in the Nice Nav widget.

All I did was add "exclude=17757" (not `<?php wp_list_pages('exclude=17757'` ); ?>) in the box and it now works fine. [This](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-exclude-pages-3?replies=4#post-4560846) post helped me.

Sorry, I could'nt answer my own question.

Comment: I'm afraid, I never used Nice Navigation. But have you tried: in wp-admin > appearance > menus; then choosing the menu you want to modify, **uncheck** "`Automatically add new top-level pages`" and save?

Comment: Thanks, I tried this - did'nt work. That box is already unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/exclude-pages/

If Nice navigation uses wp_list_pages to show the pages in the menu, it should work.

Comment: Yes, I just found this plugin and others say it works fine! But I'd rather keep plugins to a minimum and also, it seems to me it hasn't been updated for a while. Yes, you are right, Nice navigation uses wp_list_pages.